# Microsoft Bot Framework JSON Data Not Getting

Tags: c#, json, bots, asp.net-web-api-routing, botframework

When I am sending Data to My Bot I am getting reply but I am not getting JSON data in right container. 
And when I am testing this on https://dev.botframework.com/ the getting **malformed data error** 
Anycan explain me about it.

[image: Result Not Getting Perfectly]

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking the whitespace beside your text.

Answer (score 0):

The json is only displayed when you select an entry in the chat panel.

Make sure you are replying with contentType='application/json'

Comment: This is the code I am using here we have JSON but in my output I am not getting
http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/#building-your-bot

Answer (score 0):

From the picture I can not see your app ID and secret 
You should provide ID and secret and check again
Hope it solves the problem